# git branch -h created branch with name '-h'. Is this expected?

Tags: git, git-branch

As seen is image, not sure how the branches `-h` `-merged` `--help` got created

[image: Please click here for image showing all branches in local repo]

How to delete unwanted branches[/accidentally created] branches?

**Update** *text from git bash[Windows]*

`$ git branch -a
* calc
  master
  –-help
  –h
  –merged
  remotes/origin/master`

Comment: Please don't post images of text or code. Use the "copy" operation provided by your OS (Ctrl-C or Cmd-C) and paste the text as text into the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely

Comment: Thanks to user:a_horse_with_no_name.
@axiac as this is my first question , Stackoverflow did not allowed me to post an image inside description.

Comment: Use `git help branch` in your console or read the online documentation of [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). All strings you put in the command line that are not valid options are interpreted as branch names or other reference names, depending on their position.

Comment: `-h` , `--help` are valid options only. But still branches are created.
 even when tried -merged got below response
`$ git branch -D -merged`

`error: did you mean `--merged` (with two dashes ?)`

Comment: for the above created branche `-h` `--help` `-merged`,
I am unable to perform any of the operations like `checkout` or `delete` or `push` to remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that those branches are *not* named `-h`, `-merged`, and so on, but are instead named `–h`, `–merged`, and so on.  It's still difficult to tell, but the second set of names are spelled with an en-dash as the first character, rather than with a hyphen as the first character. An en-dash is Unicode character U+2013.

The keyboard method for inputting such a character is up to the OS and/or keyboard and/or other software: there are few standards here.  (On MacOS, the easiest way for me to type it is to hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and press the <kbd>-</kbd> key.)

To deal with it programmatically, you can use Python.  For instance, in Python 3:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> s = subprocess.check_output('git branch', shell=True).split(b'\n')
```

Printing the value in `s` now produces the branch names as a list of byte-strings. In my case, after creating a branch named `–merged`, one of them (`s[5]` in my test repository here) is:

```
b'  \xe2\x80\x93merged'
```

which shows the UTF-8 encoded sequence for en-dash:

```
>>> s[5].decode('utf8') == '  \N{en dash}merged'
True
>>> s[5].decode('utf8') == '  \u2013merged'
True
```

To delete it, I can invoke `git branch -D` from Python again:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call('git branch -D \N{en dash}merged', shell=True)
Deleted branch –merged (was 4ede3d42df).
0
```

(Note that under Python 2.7, this is all a bit different as the built in string type is equivalent to the `bytes` type, rather than the Python 2.7 `unicode` type.)

Comment: Thanks torek for the explanation.
I updated question with the text from git bash.

Comment: I understood somehow the command entered is `–`  *U+2013 : EN DASH* instead of `-` *U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen or minus sign}*.
Thanks for your help. I am able to access those branches with `–` character.

Comment: Most likely you copied text from a webpage to learn git, and it used the wrong symbol.